# selenium "Select" is not working and i am not sure why, please teach

Tags: selenium, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a bot as a side project. So the automated flow will be the "bot" opens up my browser, then the intended link, log in and select items from a dropdown button.

So far i managed to open my browser, open my link and log in automatically with my email address. But after logging in, i am unable to select what i wanted under the dropdown button and i am not even sure why.

I have try to find my element by id and it returns a "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable".

Currently, the code i have is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
driver.get("https://connect.com/my-dashboard")
login = driver.find_element_by_id('Email')
login.send_keys('user@email.com')


# click the 'Next' button
driver.find_element_by_class_name('move-right').click()

# select option under dropdown button
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('siteId'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Entity A')
```

in the end, it returns:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have clicked into "Investigate" for the button and it is as follows:

```
<p-dropdown _ngcontent-anw-c314="" appdropdownposition="" formcontrolname="siteSelector" styleclass="fixed-width small-medium" dropdownicon="pwc-icon icon-caret-down" inputid="siteId" optionlabel="label" class="dashboard-controls__quick-nav u-m-r-1 ng-tns-c66-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><div class="ng-tns-c66-2 fixed-width small-medium p-dropdown p-component"><div class="p-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c66-2"><input type="text" readonly="" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-tns-c66-2" id="siteId"></div><!----><span class="ng-tns-c66-2 p-dropdown-label p-inputtext p-placeholder ng-star-inserted">- Select -</span><!----><!----><!----><div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="p-dropdown-trigger ng-tns-c66-2"><span class="p-dropdown-trigger-icon ng-tns-c66-2 pwc-icon icon-caret-down"></span></div><!----></div></p-dropdown>

<div class="ng-tns-c66-2 fixed-width small-medium p-dropdown p-component"><div class="p-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c66-2"><input type="text" readonly="" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-tns-c66-2" id="siteId"></div><!----><span class="ng-tns-c66-2 p-dropdown-label p-inputtext p-placeholder ng-star-inserted">- Select -</span><!----><!----><!----><div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="p-dropdown-trigger ng-tns-c66-2"><span class="p-dropdown-trigger-icon ng-tns-c66-2 pwc-icon icon-caret-down"></span></div><!----></div>

<div class="p-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c66-2"><input type="text" readonly="" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-tns-c66-2" id="siteId"></div>

<input type="text" readonly="" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-tns-c66-2" id="siteId">
```

I have no idea how else to do this, I only knew how to work on dropdown with "id", not sure if i can do it with html or "class".

Or i should put a waiting time. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line `selenium.webdriver.support.ui as Select`

You assign `Select` alias to the module `import selenium.webdriver.support.ui`. This is not `Select` class so you cannot deal with this alias as you would do with `Select` class.

I would suggest to have such import (to avoid confusions):

```py
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as uiClasses
```

and then use:

```py
select = uiClasses.Select(driver.find_element_by_id('siteId'))
```

Comment: Hi i did a quick check and realised that this code didnt work because there is no "select" function in the page html. is it possible to work it out with xpath or any other way ? i am completely lost.

Comment: Your code reports `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` which is cased by what I explained and fixed by what I showed.

Comment: hi Alexey, i have tried running as suggested. however, after i have added in the uiclasses, a different error message popped up and confirms that i should not be using the <select> node, because my html does not consist of <select>. the error message returns - "UnexpectedTagNameException(
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>". I think it has to be done another way

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention to the `HTML` the you've shared, `Select wouldn't` work.

**Pro tip :**

`Select` will only work if you have a `HTML` with `Select` and `options tag.`

### Solution

Try to click directing with Explicit waits.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "siteId"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Entity A']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```